# undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class при настройке связи model-view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Нужно связать форму с моделью. Выходит ошибка когда пытаюсь создать новую галерею с фотографиями

```
undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class
```

**Есть контроллер:** **/app/controllers/admin/gallery_controller**

```
    class Admin::GalleryController < ApplicationController       
      def new
        @gallery_photo = GalleryPhoto.new
      end
```

**Eсть модель:** **/app/model/gallery_photo.rb**

```
    class GalleryPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
       mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    end
```

**и форма:** **/app/views/admin/gallery/_form.hrml.slim**

```
= simple_form_for ([:admin, @gallery_photo, method: :post]) do |f|
```

**роуты:** **/config/routes.rb**

```
    namespace :admin do 
     resources :gallery, expect: [ :show ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= simple_form_for ([:admin, @gallery_photo, method: :post, action: :new]) do |f|
```

попробуй-ка

Comment: пробовал вроде так не помогает.
спасибо, но ответ уже нашел.